# Knockout-Sortable: Exclude item from sort list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I'm sorting a collection using knockout-sortable and I have a "new" row that should always remain empty and at the bottom of the list. I can cancel drops "after" this row by checking positions in beforeMove, but it would be even better if I could prevent the area below this row from appearing as a droppable target in the first place.

Is this possible? The row itself *is* a real element in the collection I'm sorting on and *is* in the container I'm binding with sortable:, and these things would be very difficult to change.

```
<div id="main">
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
    <div class="container" data-bind="sortable: tasks">
        <div class="item">
            <span data-bind="visible: !$root.isTaskSelected($data)">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $root.selectedTask"></a>
            </span>
            <span data-bind="visibleAndSelect: $root.isTaskSelected($data)">
                <input data-bind="value: name, event: { blur: $root.clearTask }" />
            </span>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: addTask">Add Task</a>
</div>
```

A [basic sortable JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelhoward/hw9B2/540/). I want dropping below the "Enter a new task" row to be impossible.

Comment: Of course it is possible...  Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `items` [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) of jQuery UI's sortable for this purpose.

The idea would be that you place a class on the items that you actually want to be sortable and then use the `items` option to select them.

This class could be from a computed.  The computed in your case could potentially be related to the last item in the list.

When you bind, it would look like:  `sortable: { data: items, options: { items: '.good-items' } }`

Here is a basic sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mBjHN/